# browser.takeScreenshot() takes 2 different images of same image if runs multiple times

Tags: protractor

I have a scenario where i had to compare images.For this i am taking 2 images one for baseline and one for actual using the `browser.takeScreenShot()` method.

However, when i am comparing both images the comparison fails(using Blink-diff npm) eventhough both images are taken using same code.

so is this a problem with `browser.takeScreenShot().`

So have a look the images both images are taken using the above method but still there is difference a little pixel difference.

[image]

Comment: That looks like there's a difference in rendering, not a difference in how `takeScreenShot()` is working.  It's a minor frontend adjustment that is throwing off your pixel comparison, screenshot functionality is working fine

Comment: So how can i solve this...why its rendering different any idea?